# contain operation on hashmap dependant on size of hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

As per my understanding on hashmap

Question 1:- 
**For Hashmap returning the unique hashcode for each key**

> time to determine whether a object is contained in hashmap is constant
>   and does not depend on size of hashmap

Question 2:- 
**For Hashmap returning the same hashcode for each key but retrning false for equals method**

> time to determine whether a object is contained in hashmap is dependant on size of hashmap

Is that true ?

Comment: When you read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), what did it say?

Comment: @Mark Peters I did not find similar kind of statement on javadoc.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally considered that hashmap look ups only take O(1) time. This is the average time for look up. But in the worst case scenario it can be O(n) as well. For an example if a linked list is used in the implementation of hashmap this scenario can occur. But it can be avoided if self-balancing trees are used which reduces the worst case scenario to O(log n) time.

Comment: HashMaps are actually implemented using linked list.You must mean when all elements fall into same buckets,then it will be O(n)

Comment: HashMaps are implemented using linked lists. That is true. What I meant is that you can expect a better time in the worst case if you are using self-balancing trees. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There is an error in the last statement. Should read "O(log(n))" for the tree implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If we have an appropriately written hash function, then yes order of retrieval comes out to be of O(1).

Think of it this way, if your hash function is written appropriately, so that elements are distributed across buckets then the time to search an element would be proportional to the size of bucket. Now, if you have a constant size bucket and number of buckets or memory size is not a constraint, then you will be able to retrieve the element in constant time.

Regarding your second question: Yes if you have a hash function returning same hashcode, then the order of retrieval of element will be proportional to the size of hashmap also called O(n)